# for loop calling two different files (same name, different extension) across several files

Tags: bash, perl, for-loop

I have several files. I need to run a *perl* script calling all the files in a folder, simultaneously calling one file with extension *.pep* and another that is a similar file and matches the same name but different extension, *.pep.nuc* (like `Oh01.pep` and `Oh001.pep.nuc`)

I have this script so far, but I am missing something of course.

```
for file *.pep; do ./script.pl  *.pep *.pep.nuc > "${file%.*}.nucleo"; done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
for file in *.pep; do
    ./script.pl  "$file" "${file}.nuc" > "${file%.pep}.nucleo";
done
```